# Split list into sets using Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

There are plenty of seemingly related Linq questions, however a quick browse through the content doesn't seem to answer my question specifically enough for my limited intelligence to grasp.

We have a table named `PropertyInteractions` in which is stored threaded messages via a thread id, the thread identifier is the `Id` of the initial interaction record. Given the following Linq query (which retrieves all interactions concerning a user), how might I split `interactions` into lists of `PropertyInteraction`s grouped by `Id`?

```
Dim interactions = (From interaction In propertyItem.PropertyInteractions _
                    Where (interaction.SenderId = CurrentUser.ID OrElse _
                           interaction.RecipientId = CurrentUser.ID) AndAlso _
                           interaction.InteractionType = InteractionType.ViewRequest _
                    Order By interaction.ThreadId _
                    Select interaction)
```

EDIT:

Given Jon's input, this is what I have come to at the moment, although it may be subject to change...

```
Dim interactions = _
    (From interaction In propertyItem.PropertyInteractions _
     Where (interaction.SenderId = CurrentUser.ID OrElse _
            interaction.RecipientId = CurrentUser.ID) AndAlso _
            interaction.InteractionType = InteractionType.ViewRequest _
     Order By interaction.ThreadId _
     Group interaction By interaction.ThreadId Into Group)
```

Comment: Your ordering is a bit weird now... why are you ordering the grouped view on the result of ordering by `interaction.SendDate`. That does not compute... :)

Comment: As has just been made apparent. ;) What I was trying to attempt with the ordering has become irrelevant now anyway, so I can just sick with the grouping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just want:

```
Group interaction By interaction.Id Into Group
```

See the [docs for the Group By clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531412.aspx) for more information. (It looks like it works subtly differently from the similar C# query expression syntax; VB experts may be around to give more detailed advice.)

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim groupedInteractions = interactions.GroupBy(Function(i) i.Id)
```

Comment: There, @Martinho, thanks for the C#->VB.Net conversion. Not doing much VB coding so the lambda syntax doesn't come easily.